# Is the exact lua binary able to be specified in the luarocks compilation options?

Tags: luarocks

Right now I have to create a symlink to the lua runtime I'm using:

```
ln -s $PREFIX/bin/lua-tarantool  $PREFIX/bin/tarantool
```

Then I have to use   `--lua-suffix="-tarantool"` for the `./configure` options.

Is there a way to specify the exact name of the binary without resorting to symbolic links? For example: `--with-lua-bin=$PREFIX/bin/tarantool`

I checked the options and there doesn't seem to be anything like that: https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-Unix#Customizing_your_settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the following in your `~/.luarocks/config.lua` file:

```
lua_interpreter = "/some_dir/bin/tarantool"
variables = {
   LUA = "/some_dir/bin/tarantool"
}
```

You might need to tweak the first line of the `luarocks` script, though (or run it with `tarantool /path/to/luarocks`).

But you can also ask yourself: do you need to run LuaRocks with `tarantool`? It should be possible to install plain Lua, LuaRocks and Tarantool, and configure LuaRocks to use plain Lua, but to install modules to the Tarantool path.